# Rails Счетчик просмотра поста?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Всем еще раз привет.

Дошел до момента подсчета количества просмотревших пост и никак не могу определится.

### Может кто подскажет на своем опыте?

Сайт новостной, новостей более 10 000.
Сбор нужен для сортировки по популярности просмотров за сутки, неделю, а так-же для редактора для информативности.

Почитал куча всего, кто говорит что использовать для этого базу плохо, кто говорит что есть решения проще.

**В общем что нашел из Gem-ов**

```
1) https://github.com/biola/punching_bag
```

В принципе нормальный, вся статистика есть, за любой период

```
2)https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist
```

Вроде как выходит тоже не плох, тоже умеет все что модуль выше, но при этом есть некая защита от ботов и запись ip посетителя дабы исключить повторное кручение счетчика. Даже выходит что этот будет получше, так как первый пишет лишь хиты и защиты от ботов и записи Ip у него нет вовсе, каждый новый заход = новый хит

```
3)https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/page_visit_tracker
```

Тоже какой-то но не разбирался что и как с ним, может кто знает скажет.

Хотелось бы услышать тех кто уже решал данную задачу. Конечно хотелось бы видеть защиту от повторного кручения с одного Ip. Ну и конечно статистику за нужный период для сортировки и информации. Вроде как в этом побеждает вариант 2, но хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще нужно исходить из количества посетителей. На каждый просмотр будет нужно делать несколько дополнительных запросов.
Если посетителей немного то это нормально. Если много - могут возникнуть проблемы с производительностью.

Из этих гемов Impressionist выглядит посвежее и поаккуратнее.
Кроме того, он, вроде, умеет с монго работать. Правда я не понял, можно ли использовать монго только для него или, все приложение должно его использовать.

Можно попробовать изобрести свой велосипед. Я бы попытался хранить статистику в монго или редис.

Comment: Да посетителей примерно 15-20 тысяч в сутки